# Dashed line as a mark in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I am trying to turn some markers into a dashed line in this diagram. However, I can only change them all at once. I need the "a", "b" and "c" to remain as a solid line, and turn "d" and "e" into a dashed line. It would be nice to label the separation between "d" and "e" with a curly bracket as shown below. How can I do that?

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   every axis plot post/.style={mark=-,thick,mark size=10mm},
   xtick style={draw=none},
   xticklabels={,,},
   xmin=-0.9,
   xmax=1.1,
   ymin=14.5,
   ymax=19.5,
   cycle list name=black white,
   only marks, 
   x=2cm, y=1cm,
   every node near coord/.append style={font=\small,yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=\myshift}
 ]
\addplot [nodes near coords={\labelz},
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{3}\as\myshift}] 
table[header=false] {
0 15.152 a 15mm
0 18.182 b 15mm
0 18.868 c 15mm
0 18.943 d -15mm
0 18.107 e -15mm
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Do you need the plot for some other reason? -It would be simple just to `\draw` the lines.

Comment: `\draw[dashed, thick] (-0.5, 17) -- (0.5, 17) node[right, xshift=0.3cm] {z};`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this, not sure if it's the best solution:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   xtick style={draw=none},
   xticklabels={,,},
   xmin=-0.9,
   xmax=1.1,
   ymin=14.5,
   ymax=19.5,
   cycle list name=black white,
   only marks, 
   x=2cm, y=1cm,
   every node near coord/.append style={font=\small,yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=\myshift}
 ]
\addplot [mark=-,thick,mark size=10mm,nodes near coords={\labelz},
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{3}\as\myshift}] 
table[header=false] {
0 15.152 a 15mm
0 18.182 b 15mm
0 18.868 c 15mm
};
\addplot [mark=-,thick,dashed,mark size=10mm,nodes near coords={\labelz},
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{3}\as\myshift}] 
table[header=false] {
0 18.943 {} -15mm
0 18.107 {} -15mm
};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}]
(-0.55,18.943) -- (-0.55,18.107) node [midway,xshift=-5mm] {d};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]